# getting items from an embed array in discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I got an interaction embed using this code :

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    const raidembed = interaction.message.embeds
    console.log(raidembed)
```

And this is what it returns :

```
[
  Embed {
    data: {
      type: 'rich',
      title: 'RAID DU : A :',
      image: [Object],
      footer: [Object],
      fields: [Array],
      description: '# Caveau des Incarnations\n### <:skull:1193157255407882340> Normal (:)',
      color: 9124820
    }
  }
]
```

I need to edit the fields of the embed, and i am currently using the `embed.spliceFields()` method.
How do i get to the fields array of the embed array ?
I tried `console.log(raidembed.fields)` or `console.log(raidembed.data.fields` but they all return "undefined".

It looks to me like an array inside an object, inside an other object and inside an other array :

```
[object { object: { array: []}}]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So interaction.message.embeds returns an array. Before you access the object you need to access the respective embed from the array first.

```js
let raidEmbed = interaction.message.embeds;

//It seems that in your case you're only getting one embed so access it like this:

let raidData = raidEmbed[0].data;

//Now do what you want with the data.
```